# TypeError: parse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'stream'

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse,JsonResponse
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework import parsers
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from .models import Article
from .serializer import Articleserializer
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
# Create your views here.
def artical_list(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        article= Article.objects.all()
        serializer=Articleserializer(article,many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data,safe=False)
    elif request.method=='POST':
        data=JSONParser.parse(request)
        serializer=Articleserializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data,status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

this is my serializer class
from django.db.models import fields
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Article

```
class Articleserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Article
        fields= ['id','title','author']
```

this is my model class

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    
   

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

when I post the data using postman giving this error please help me django rest freamwork is

Comment: Please show the full traceback in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JSONParser` should be instantiated. The `parse` method is a *normal* method, not a classmethod. So you need a instance for it to work:

```py
JSONParser().parse(request)  # Instead of JSONParser.parse(request)
```

Answer (score -1):

parse JSON data, this is not the correct way to do it. You should use JSONParser() instead.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from .models import Article
from .serializers import ArticleSerializer
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def article_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        articles = Article.objects.all()
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(articles, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
    
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = ArticleSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

**When using Postman for testing, ensure sure you're supplying a legitimate JSON payload in the POST request body.**